# Meaning of Image$$PAGING_IMAGE_LOAD_END$$Base

Tags: arm, paging

I have a section of code mentioning the following.

```
Image$$PAGING_IMAGE_LOAD_END$$Base
```

What does this mean? An explanation or help of any kind would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It's a special symbol generated [by the ARM linker](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.kui0101a/armlink_chdcgbjd.htm).

```
Image$$region_name$$Base    Execution address of the region.
Image$$region_name$$Length  Execution region length in bytes excluding ZI length.
Image$$region_name$$Limit   Address of the byte beyond the end of the non-ZI part of the execution region.
[...etc...]
```